# Singleton instance scope confusion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

I am learning Design Patterns in JavaScript and I was going through the `Singleton` design pattern. Here is the code:

```
var SingletonTester = (function () {
    // options: an object containing configuration options for the singleton
    // e.g var options = { name: 'test', pointX: 5};
    function Singleton(options) {
        // set options to the options supplied or an empty object if none provided.
        options = options || {};
        //set the name parameter
        this.name = 'SingletonTester';
        //set the value of pointX
        this.pointX = options.pointX || 6;
        //set the value of pointY
        this.pointY = options.pointY || 10;
    }
            // this is our instance holder
    var instance;

    // this is an emulation of static variables and methods
    var _static = {
        name: 'SingletonTester',
        // This is a method for getting an instance
        // It returns a singleton instance of a singleton object
        getInstance: function (options) {
            if (instance === undefined) {
                instance = new Singleton(options);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
    return _static;
})();
var singletonTest = SingletonTester.getInstance({
    pointX: 5
});
var singletonTest1 = SingletonTester.getInstance({
    pointX: 15
});
console.log(singletonTest.pointX); // outputs 5
console.log(singletonTest1.pointX); // outputs 5
```

I do not understand why the variable `instance` gets some value when `singletonTest1` is initiated.

Comment: In JS, you don't need `Singleton`, just use a global var.

Comment: Second that ^, but if you still want a Singleton emulation, then Google for "javascript singleton enforcer". There are some Git projects which do that.
Makes no proper sense anyway. JS is JS.

Comment: @DavinTryon This is already a singleton pattern, it works fine. My confusion was, how come `instance` variable had value when `singletonTest1` was initiated. At least read the question before comment.

Comment: @Ingmars question is not about I want singleton pattern,  it is about something else.  I wanted to ask why `instance` variable was still alive when `singletonTest1` was initiated.

Comment: @BharatSoni the reason this works is because `SingletonTester` is a global var.

Comment: @DavinTryon I understand `SingletonTester` is a global property, but `instance` is a private variable of `SingletonTester`. How it can have value when it is called again. Could you please explain it a bit more.. will really appreciate that.

Comment: Do you understand closures?

Answer (score 1):

When the module `SingletonTester` is created, it is also called:

```
var SingletonTester = (function () {
    // ... stuff in here
    var instance;
})(); // <--- here
```

That last line is a function application `();`.  After that application the `SingletonTester` module contains all of it's enclosed state.

Since `instance` is a property closed over by the `SingletonTester` closure, instance is *alive* for the entire existence of `SingletonTester`.

**Side note:** Singleton pattern is primarily about creating a thread-safe static instance for sharing across a process.  Since JavaScript is single-threaded, this is obviously not a problem.  You can instead keep things simple and just use a global var.

Comment: Ah, now I get it, got confused. Of course its a closure. Thanks a lot Davin.